# Set operations on cell level

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a `DataFrame` with values in one column being a `set`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'song': 'Despacito', 'genres': {'pop','rock'}}, 
                   {'song': 'We will rock you', 'genres': {'rock'}},
                   {'song': 'Fur Eliza', 'genres': {'piano'}}])

print(df)
```

```
               song       genres
0         Despacito  {rock, pop}
1  We will rock you       {rock}
2         Fur Eliza      {piano}
```

How do I select rows with `genres` overlapping with expected genres? For instance, I would expect

```py
df[~df['genres'].intersection({'rock', 'metal'})]
```

to return first two songs:

```
               song       genres
0         Despacito  {rock, pop}
1  We will rock you       {rock}
```

Obviously, this will fail, because `Series` does not have `intersection()` method, but you get the idea. 
Is there a way to implement it with pandas `DataFrame` or `DataFrame` is not the right structure for my goal?

Comment: What will be the expected output?

Comment: @MayankPorwal First two rows of a DataFrame, because their genres overlap with expected set. I've updated my question with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdisjoint#frozenset.isdisjoint) method with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = df[~df['genres'].map({'rock', 'metal'}.isdisjoint)]
print (df)
               song       genres
0         Despacito  {rock, pop}
1  We will rock you       {rock}
```